# char* (*name())[]; Is this statement array of function pointers?

Tags: c, function, syntax, declaration, function-declaration

This statement has made me thinking. I end up with a conclusion function pointer returns the array of character. But I am not able to give proper reasoning to myself.

Comment: When in doubt about a type, [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=char*+%28*name%28%29%29%5B%5D) it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of code that uses this declaration (and compiles and runs successfully)?

Comment: It's a function taking any parameter and returning an array pointer with `char*` items. Don't waste time trying to understand crappy code like this, use typedefs instead and always pass array pointers as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it like this (using Clockwise/Spiral rule):

```
char* (*name())[];
```

1) Find the identifier.

```
char* (*name())[];
        ^^^^
```

"name is a"

2) Move right.

```
char* (*name())[];
            ^^
```

"name is a function accepting any parameter and returning"

3) Can't move right anymore because of the right parenthesis, so move left.

```
char* (*name())[];
       ^
```

"name is a function accepting any parameter and returning pointer to"

4) Can't move left anymore because of the left parenthesis, so keep going
   right.

```
char* (*name())[];
               ^^
```

"name is a function accepting any parameter and returning pointer to an array"

5) Can't move right anymore because we're out of symbols, so go left.

```
char* (*name())[];
    ^
```

"name is a function accepting any parameter and returning pointer to an array of pointers to"

6) And finally, keep going left, because there's nothing left on the right.

```
char* (*name())[];
^^^^
```

"name is a function accepting any parameter and returning pointer to an array of pointers to char".

Answer (score 3):

Declarations present a “picture” of how something will be used. The declaration `char* (*name())[];` says `* (*name())[]` is a `char`.

- Then `(*name())[]` is a pointer to a `char`.
- Then `(*name())` is an array of pointers to `char`.
- Then `*name()` is an array of pointers to `char`.
- Then `name()` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`.
- Then `name` is a function that returns a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Variable declarations like this are read **inside out, following operator precedence**.

In this case:

- `name` is the name of a ...
- `name()` function (precedence, the `()` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator!), which returns a ...
- `*name()` pointer to ...
- `(*name())[]` an array (precendence, the `[]` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator!) of ...
- `*(*name())[]` pointers to ...
- `char*(*name())[]` characters.

This is mostly equivalent to Eric Postpischil's method, but it shows much more clearly where the operator precedence comes into play.

Btw: Once you've wrapped your head around this variable declaration, there'll be no variable declaration in C that you won't be able to understand.

Comment: Huh? Operator precedence doesn't apply at all, since this is all declarations, not an expression. Your answer doesn't make any sense - you can't apply operator precedence to declarations.

Comment: @Lundin: The grammar for declarators mirrors the grammar for expressions. And the rules for precedence in expression derive from the grammar, so the same grammar (or, for declarators, a subset) gives the same precedence.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That reasoning leads to all manner of strange conclusions. How am I to read `const int a, *b;` thinking like that? _"The comma operator has lowest precedence so `a` is const int and then `b` is a pointer of unknown type. Only `a` is const-qualified since the left side is fully evaluated first, before `*b`"_... which is clearly not correct.

Comment: @Lundin: Read it the same way you read it in a function call, `x(a, *b)`. The comma is not a comma operator there either. The grammar for *declarators* is the grammar for *declarators*, not the grammar for *declarations*. In a *declaration*, the declarators are in *init-declarators* an *init-declarator-list*. Commas separate elements of the list, and those commas are not parts of declarators. And, whether you like it or not, the interpretation of declarators is in fact specified via the grammar. The grammar controls the precedence. It is what tells you `*f()` is `*(f())`, not `(*f)()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is a function prototype. Function returning pointer to array of `char *` pointers. Function is taking unspecified parameters

If you want to have function pointer returning array of pointers to `char` it has to be declared like this

```
 char* ((*name)())[];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* (*name())[];
```

With this statement you are declaring a function called `name` which is permissibly taking any parameter and returns a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`, not a function pointer which returns an array of `char`.

It is the declaration or "prototype" of the function `name`.

Note that you also need a definition (what the function actually is doing) for the function `name` in order to use `name` in your source code.

If you want to determine a certain type of C construct you can use the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) made by David Anderson; but not to confuse with [Anderson`s Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%27s_rule_(computer_science)) made by Ross J. Anderson, which is something quite distinct.